# Is it possible to have different style font when on a selected tab in UISegmentedControl?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios4

I have written this code to set font attributes for UISegmentedControl for normal state and highlighted state but its not working. Please help me point out why.

```
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0f], UITextAttributeFont,

                            [UIColor blackColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,

                            nil];

NSDictionary *boldAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12.0f], UITextAttributeFont,

                            [UIColor blackColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,

                            nil];



[self.tab setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[self.tab setTitleTextAttributes:boldAttributes forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

I want selected text to be bold and otherwise it should be normal.

Comment: I managed to change text color only, setting font didn't make any change

Comment: Have you tried UIControlStateSelected?

Comment: No I didn't try that, right now I added one more line: [self.tab setTitleTextAttributes:boldAttributes forState:UIControlStateSelected];

Comment: Why is this tagged as iOS4? The `setTitleTextAttributes:forState:` method of `UISegmentedControl` was added in iOS 5.0.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried it like the following

```
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17], UITextAttributeFont,
                        [UIColor blackColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                        nil];
[_segmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
NSDictionary *highlightedAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor    whiteColor] forKey:UITextAttributeTextColor];
[_segmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:highlightedAttributes  forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

And to set the font

```
 [UIFont fontWithName:@"FontName" size:desiredsize.f]
```

Also change the highlighted to selected.

Comment: I changed the tinted color earlier for different tabs to lighter shades of blue and green as it was required, so I can't change it to white color because it can't be seen then. One way to see if is to bold it and for some reason my code isn't working.

Comment: Also I just tried to change the highlighted to selected and same results

Comment: You can add your own tint to instead of the color I have in my code. And for using bold just put a - at the end of the name of the font. It generally works for me but remember that the for has to be part of the uifont family.

Comment: Yeah I put both codes for both UIControlStateHighlighted and UIControlStateSelected and gave them the bolded font, but still not working. To be safe I used systemFont and boldSystemFont to ensure I am not adding fonts that don't exist.

Comment: Try changing self.tab to segment controller. That maybe your issue.

Comment: the tab is just a variable for UISegmentedControl, so that is already UISegmentedControl

Comment: Oh yes when I initialized tab I used UISegmentedControl this time, still no progress... is there any other issue?

Comment: Nothing I can see from the code posted. Is there any more code related to segment that you can share?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is dated, but for those who are looking for a solution in swift you might want to try this approach:

```
func stylizeFonts(){
    let normalFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 16.0)
    let boldFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 16.0)

    let normalTextAttributes: [NSObject : AnyObject] = [
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor(),
        NSFontAttributeName: normalFont!
    ]

    let boldTextAttributes: [NSObject : AnyObject] = [
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor(),
        NSFontAttributeName : boldFont!,
    ]

    self.setTitleTextAttributes(normalTextAttributes, forState: .Normal)
    self.setTitleTextAttributes(normalTextAttributes, forState: .Highlighted)
    self.setTitleTextAttributes(boldTextAttributes, forState: .Selected)
}
```

Be sure to add stylizeFonts() in your viewDidLoad or as a separate function if you are subclassing.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
[self.tab setTitleTextAttributes:boldAttributes forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

to

```
[self.tab setTitleTextAttributes:boldAttributes forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```